# Python function loop that returns multiple dictionaries but unable to return all values of my loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have 2 functions below.  When I loop though list_of_dicts in my dict_list() I am able to print out each dictionary in this list but when I return i in dict_list() and try to print out the return in get_dicts(i) it only returns / prints {'id': '33333', 'env': 'dev', 'cost': '250.00'} aka the first iteration of my loop.  How can I return each dictionary so I can can then modify that data in get_dicts(i) something like if i['env'] == 'prod' i['env'] = "production" just an example but trying to avoid creating a list if possible.

```
def dict_list():
     list_of_dicts = [{'id': '12345', 'env': 'prod', 'cost': '50.00'}
                , {'id': '67890', 'env': 'dev', 'cost': '100.00'}
                , {'id': '11111', 'env': 'stage', 'cost': '150.00'}
                , {'id': '22222', 'env': 'prod', 'cost': '200.00'}
                , {'id': '33333', 'env': 'dev', 'cost': '250.00'}]
for i in list_of_dicts:
    print(i)
    return i

def get_dicts(i):
    print(i)
        

def main():
    i = dict_list()
    get_dicts(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a list?  That is typically how you return multiple values.  Your only other option is to turn the function into a generator by using [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) instead of `return`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When you use `i` as the iterator for your loop, it stores the last iteration when the loop ends. [Or on the first iteration if you return then. Edited because the indentation in the original question changed.] You then return it from your function. Either `yield` or just use the list of dicts in `get_dicts` and forget about `dict_list` altogether

Comment: `return` inside `loop` will work only once

Comment: to answer the question of why I would like to avoid a list.  I want to modify these dicts with a loop in my other function.  something along the lines of:

 for value in i:
  if i['env'] == 'prod' i['env'] = "production"

with a list of dictionaries I dont think I i can do that unless i pull all of my dicts out of that list.  With lists I can only parse data by indexing and this will not scale when working with larger dicts

Comment: really sorry about the formatting I need to get the hang of stackoverflow comments

Comment: as per the second comment in this case yes I can just perform that operation in my fist function but that will not work with my actual data.  In my actual data i am getting dicts from another function that is looping multiple dicts.  They are not even in a list its just multiple dict outputs  and from those I wanted to do some sorting and parsing so this example is as close as I can get to what I am having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_list():
    list_of_dicts = [{'id': '12345', 'env': 'prod', 'cost': '50.00'}
            , {'id': '67890', 'env': 'dev', 'cost': '100.00'}
            , {'id': '11111', 'env': 'stage', 'cost': '150.00'}
            , {'id': '22222', 'env': 'prod', 'cost': '200.00'}
            , {'id': '33333', 'env': 'dev', 'cost': '250.00'}]
    return list_of_dicts


def main():
    for dicts in dict_list():
        if dicts['env'] == 'prod':
             print(dicts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

have you try this method?

Comment: that would work but I cant perform this loop in main it needs to be a stand alone function it seems I may just have to create a list if there is no other way.  thank you for this suggestion though!